# Validation Exception. Need assistance

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

So I have this assignment where I have to create a Winforms table data and display it.

I have created first form (DataGridView) to display the detail of the product view with function add, modify buttons to it, and the second form which allows me to enter the product id and product name and save the data as well.

But while putting my code on the second form and put the: if (validation section) I got an error if it doesn't exist or I need a definition to it. However I will following a guide example step by step but I'm not sure how they fix or overcame that issues.

```
namespace TravelProduct
{ 
    public partial class frmModifyProduct : Form 
    { 
        public bool isAdd; // main form sets it - is it Add or Modify?
        public Product currentProduct; // main form sets it - the current products

        public frmModifyProduct() { InitializeComponent(); }

        private void frmModifyProduct_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (isAdd)
            {
                txtproductid.Enabled = true;
                txtproductid.Focus(); // focus of the first text box
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayCurrentProduct(); // display data of the current product
                txtproductid.Enabled = false; // code is not updatable
                txtproductname.Focus(); // focus on description
            }


        }
        private void DisplayCurrentProduct()
        {
            txtproductid.Text = currentProduct.ProductId.ToString();
            txtproductname.Text = currentProduct.ProdName;

        }
        private void ClearTextBoxes()
        {
            txtproductid.Text = "";
            txtproductname.Text = "";
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (isAdd)
            {         (this part is where  I have error on the validation part,             where I have to select using system or fix variable or something)
                if (Validator.IsPresent(txtproductid, "Productid") &&
                    Validator.IsInt32(txtproductid, "Productid") &&
                    Validator.IsCorrectLength(txtproductname, "ProductName", 10) &&
                    )
                {
                    Product newProduct = new Product // object initiallizer
                    {
                        ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(txtproductid.Text),
                        ProdName = txtproductname.Text
                    };
                    using (ProductDataContext dbContext = new ProductDataContext())
                    {
                        // insert through data context object
                        dbContext.Products.InsertOnSubmit(newProduct);
                        dbContext.SubmitChanges(); // submit to the database
                    }
                    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

                }
                else // validation  failed
                {
                    DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
                }
            }
            else // it is Modify
            {
                if (Validator.IsInt32(txtproductid, "Productid") &&
                    Validator.IsPresent(txtproductname, "ProdName")
                    )

                {
                    try
                    {

                        using (ProductDataContext dbContext = new ProductDataContext())
                        {
                            // get the product with Code from the current text box
                            Product prod = dbContext.Products.Single
                            (p => p.ProductId == Convert.ToInt32(txtproductid.Text));// lambda                           expression
                            if (prod != null)
                            {
                                prod.ProdName = txtproductname.Text;
                                dbContext.SubmitChanges();

                            }

                        }

                    }

                    catch (ChangeConflictCollection)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Another user changed or deleted the current record", "Concurrency Exception");
                        DialogResult = DialogResult.Retry;
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString());
                    }

                }
                else // validation failed
                {
                    DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what line did you got the error on? what does the error say?

Comment: he validator line, if you scroll the scrollbar near the middle,  where " if( it is modify)     it say validator not exist, but when I click to try to fix it with (ctrl . )  it show using component, and as well as other option which Im not aware or understand it

Answer (score 0):

the constructor should be like

```
public frmModifyProduct(bool isAdd_,Product currentProduct_) 
{ 
InitializeComponent();
isAdd = isAdd_;
currentProduct = currentProduct_;
}
```

Comment: if I change it, what will happen?,  any commented regarding the validation part?

Comment: the call from the main form would be : var form = new frmModifyProduct(isAdd, currentProduct); which is the product toy want to modify or null if you want to add.

Answer (score 0):

If Validator is a custom user defined class (meaning you wrote the implementation of that class) then either you need to copy the whole implementaion in this second frmModifyProduct.cs file or add a reference from the common implementation path.

If the implementation of Validator class is in some other central library then you just need the reference. Take the cursor on top of Validator and press Ctrl+dot.
Intellisense will come up with the correct reference, which you can see and select accordingly.

Comment: yes I wrote the validator class, by following an example, but not sure how they wrote in initially. I'm not sure if its in the library or how can I check?  So you mean by implementing it, I have to copy that particular validator code and insert it in to my other datagridview windows form in the view code part?  also because when I press Ctrl+dot, there other options to select from such as, "using system component", generate to variable, fix it to variable, just need to know the solution to this